# Best way to merge the same feature to other branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a terraform repo which has `master`, `release`, and `develop` branches. Each of the branch represent an environment (`Dev`, `QA`, `Prod`).

We manage changes or enhancement through feature branch. Question is after a new feature merged to `develop` branch, should we continue merging the same `feature` to `release` and `master`, or we should merge `develop` to `release`, and then merge `release` to `master`. Looks like either way will get the same the codes across all branches, but like to understand what's the best way for doing this. Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are two components to your questions. "What happens technically in Git?" and "What is a good work flow?" The first one is objective and you have answered yourself, and the second one is subjective as it is a matter of preference to which there is no right or wrong in Git. Stackoverflow is better suited for objective technical questions.

However, I am happy to give you my subjective personal preference which comes from [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). Again, this is a workflow and not *how* Git works.

Create `feature` from `develop`. Once the new feature is done, merge `feature` to `develop` and then delete `feature`. Once you are ready to do a new release, then create `release` from `master` and merge `develop` to `release`. Do QA in `release`. Then merge `release` into `master` and then delete `release`. Then rebase `develop` to `master` and repeat.